# Save a set of coordinates in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, cllocation

I having an issues on saving a set of `CLLocation`s object in Swift. I keep getting an errors of

```
[Location setLongitude:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

My Location class had many-to-one relationship with my trip class. I try to save a set of coordinates when saving my trip object as well.
Here is my Location Class, which refer on the class suggested on a thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790492/saving-swift-cllocation-in-coredata).

```
    @objc(Location)
class Location: NSManagedObject{
    @NSManaged var latitude: NSNumber!
    @NSManaged var longitude: NSNumber!
    @NSManaged var altitude: NSNumber!
    @NSManaged var timestamp: NSDate!
    @NSManaged var horizontalAccuracy: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var verticalAccuracy: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var speed: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var course: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var trip: Trip

    func initFromLocation(loc: CLLocation, currentTrip: Trip){
        self.latitude           = loc.coordinate.latitude
        self.longitude          = loc.coordinate.longitude
        self.altitude           = loc.altitude
        self.timestamp          = loc.timestamp

        self.horizontalAccuracy = loc.horizontalAccuracy > 0.0 ? loc.horizontalAccuracy : 0.0
        self.verticalAccuracy   = loc.verticalAccuracy > 0.0 ? loc.verticalAccuracy : 0.0
        self.speed              = loc.speed > 0.0 ? loc.speed : 0.0
        self.course             = loc.course > 0.0 ? loc.course : 0.0
        self.trip               = currentTrip
    }

    func location() -> CLLocation{
        return CLLocation(
            coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.latitude.doubleValue, longitude: self.longitude.doubleValue),
            altitude: self.altitude.doubleValue,
            horizontalAccuracy: self.horizontalAccuracy.doubleValue,
            verticalAccuracy: self.verticalAccuracy.doubleValue,
            course: self.course.doubleValue,
            speed: self.speed.doubleValue,
            timestamp: self.timestamp
        )

    }

}
```

Any ideas on why I unable to set the longitude in my class or what going on around?

Comment: Can you please show the code where you use your `Location` class and where error occurs?

Comment: self.longitude          = loc.coordinate.longitude

This line triggers the errors. setLongitude issues

Comment: How do you instantiate object or your `Location` class? Please show code that leads to invocation of `initFromLocation`

Comment: `let lm = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(LocationEntityName, inManagedObjectContext: contxt) as Location
            
            var locationSavingError: NSError?

            for location in tripCoordinates{
                lm.initFromLocation(location, currentTrip: tm)
                if contxt.save(&locationSavingError){
                    println("Successfully added this location \(location)")
                }
            }`
** tm is my Trip Model Object.
**tripCoordinates is an array of CLLocation of the trip
Hope this is clear enough.